# Node js file execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a sample node js file i executed it in the command prompt, but, it is not coming in the browser,

```
var http = require('http');
port = process.argv[2] || 8888;
http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
var PI = Math.PI;
exports.area = function (r) {
    var res1 = PI * r * r;
    response.end(res1, 'utf-8');
   // alert(res1);
    return res1;
};
exports.circumference = function (r) {
    var res2 = 2 * PI * r;
    response.end(res2, 'utf-8');
    //alert(res2);
    return res2;
}; 
}).listen(parseInt(port, 10));
console.log("file server running at\n => hostname " + port + "/\nCTRL + C to shutdown");
```

**strong text**
Can anyone, Please tell me where i have done the mistake

Comment: Where are you calling `area` and `circumference`? Why are there `alerts` in your node code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you currently are not writing anything to response of the request.

`response.write()`

Also you are using methods like `alert();` which are the browser methods, but the code you currently run is executed in the server side.

Currently you only declare methods but do not call out anything.

This example should work:

```
var http = require('http');
port = process.argv[2] || 8888;


http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });

    var PI = Math.PI;
    area = function(r) {
        var res1 = PI * r * r;
        response.write('Area = ' + res1);
        // alert(res1);
        return res1;
    };
    circumference = function(r) {
        var res2 = 2 * PI * r;
        response.write('circumference = ' +res2);
        //alert(res2);
        return res2;
    };

    area(32);
    response.write(' ');
    circumference(23);
    response.end();

}).listen(parseInt(port, 10));
console.log("file server running at\n => hostname " + port + "/\nCTRL + C to shutdown");
```

Comment: Is there any other way to call those methods and to show the result in the browser screen

Comment: also look at the express for more complicated web routes or read more about the ___http___ http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake,works now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470133/node-js-error-throw-new-typeerrorfirst-argument-must-be-a-string-or-buffer

Comment: Close the question, so other users can see the answer for your problem.

Comment: please tell me how to close the question

Answer (score 1):

To extend my comment about `alert` not working, here's how you could use express to do what you're asking:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.configure(function(){
    // I'll let you read the express API docs linked below to decide what you want to include here
});

app.get('/area/:radius', function(req, res, next){
    var r = req.params.radius;
    res.send(200, { area: Math.PI * r * r });
});
app.get('/circumference/:radius', function(req, res, next){
    var r = req.params.radius;
    res.send(200, { circumference: 2 * Math.PI * r });
});
http.createServer(app).listen(8888, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port 8888');
});
```

This assumes that you have included "express" in package.json and installed it with npm install. Here's the [express API documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have not end the response object, so your request is keep going 
and eventually failing u need to end the response object( with some data if required)

```
var http = require('http');
port = process.argv[2] || 8888;
http.createServer(function(request,response){
    var PI = Math.PI;
    exports.area = function (r) {
        var res1 = PI * r * r;
        alert(res1);
        return res1;
    };
    exports.circumference = function (r) {
        var res2 = 2 * PI * r;
        alert(res2);
        return res2;
    }; 
    response.end('hello');
}).listen(parseInt(port, 10));
console.log("file server running at\n => hostname " + port + "/\nCTRL + C to shutdown");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot abhi, this is working fine. One small doubt, I didnt get any alert messages in the browser, how can i get the results for the functions area and circumference

Comment: You won't be able to do that with node. As was commented elsewhere, "alert" is a client-side javascript method - it has no meaning on the server. If you want to alert the area and circumference, you'll actually have to call them here in node and return the values to the client. Additionally, it seems like you are thinking that you'll be able to call area and circumference from the browser. You won't. At least, not without sending an http request back to the server. `exports.area` exposes the area method to other modules that `require` this one but not to client-side code.